# How can I dynamically define the copy AND logic of part of my app through a web interface?

Tags: parsing, email, programming-languages, language-design, mustache

We do a lot of email AB testing. Right now all of the copy and logic for each email is hard-coded, but we want to be able to dynamically update both the copy AND the logic through a web interface (so we can test iterations more quickly and easily).

An example of the current hard-coded logic (in Ruby) might look something like this:

```
# weekly email

if @user.emailed_before?
  "Hey again #{@user.name}!"
else
  "Hey #{@user.name}!"
end
...
```

**What would be a good way to define this using pseudo-code (or some simple syntax) in a web interface?**

Are there syntaxes and parsers already optimized for this stuff?

My initial thoughts are to do something like this:

Pre-define certain variables (USER_NAME, USER_EMAILED_BEFORE, etc.), then define some basic syntax and control flow, and then update the logic and the copy in the interface like so (this particular approach is inspired by the Mustache templating engine):

```
{{ IF USER_EMAILED_BEFORE }}
<p>Hey there old friend, {{USER_NAME}}!</p>
{{ ELSE }}
<p>Hey there stranger, {{USER_NAME}}!</p>
{{ END }}
```

This would come into the server/database as text, then would be parsed into a template to be used when the actual emails are sent out.

Is this a sound approach? Is there a better and/or easier way to do this?

I would really appreciate some feedback! Thanks!

Comment: I do not know whether this is a sound approach, but there are certainly languages `already optimized for this stuff` Javascript, Perl, PHP come to mind. Certainly also Ruby and Python.